# Outputing Drupal Webform Values to Highrise

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform, highrise

I am integrating Drupal Webform with the CRM Highrise - I'm using the Highrise Drupal module (https://drupal.org/project/highrise) to create some mapping - however I want to extend the module to pass additional form values to the "background" field designated within Highrise, the issue I'm running into is that rather than passing the form value of say "Birthday Party" it's simply returning "array" in Highrise, below is the code I have right now:

```
//initial variable declaration 
$form['#get_eventtype'] = drupal_render($event_type);

//making the call to post to Highrise
case 4:
  $background = $form_state['values']['submitted'][$row['cid']];
  $background .= $form['#get_eventtype'];
  $new_person->setBackground($background);
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you dumped the value in `$background` after you retrieve it from the form? It is going to be an array and your value will be in one of the array elements. If you haven't already, I would suggest installing the [devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) to help you dig into the form structure.

Answer (score 0):

As a FYI I ended up just using [Formstack.com](http://formstack.com) - which gives you the ability to easily map custom fields created in Highrise with the form you create using Formstack.  Upon creating a form with Formstack I embedded the JavaScript tag provided and was good to go.